# How to get font size 16pt with the article class?

Tags: fontsize

How can I have the text to be 12pt and the title and introduction to be 16pt in a paper I am writing?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images

\title{test}
\author{R P}
\date{April 2023}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard classes have options `10pt` (default), `11pt` and `12pt` to setup the font sizes of the text. Depending on these options also the font size commands `\Huge`, `\huge`, `\LARGE`, `\Large`, `\large`, `\normalsize`, `\small`, `\footnotesize`, `\scriptsize` and `\tiny` are changed. The section heading usually uses `\Large`. With option `12pt` the size of `\Large` would be 17.28pt with baseline skip of 22pt. You could change this to 16pt instead and optionally also reduce the baseline skip, so would get 16pt instead of 17.28pt everywhere, `\Large` is used (e.g. the number line of `\part` headings):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{lmodern} % use free scalable fonts

\title{test}
\author{R P}
\date{April 2023}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand\Large{\@setfontsize\Large{16}{20}}% size and baselineskip reduced
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

\end{document}
```

Alternatively you can change the size used by `\section` only. This can be done either using a package like `titlesec` or just redefining or patching `\section`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{lmodern} % use free scalable fonts    \usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchcmd{\section}{\Large}{\fontsize{16}{20}\selectfont}{}{\PatchFailure}% Patch \section to use another font size and baseline skip instead of \Large

\title{test}
\author{R P}
\date{April 2023}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

\end{document}
```

Note: Depending on the fonts you are using, maybe not all sizes would be supported. Usually this would be reported in the `log` file, e.g., by messages like:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1/cmr/bx/n' in size <16> not available
(Font)              size <17.28> substituted on input line 14.
```

In the examples above, I've switched over to scalable font Latin Modern to avoid such an issue. If you'd use XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX you don't need to load package `lmodern` (and also should not do it), because these already use the OpenType version of Latin Modern as default.

But note: If you have been told, the sizes should be 12 point and 16 point, you should also recognize, that 1pt in TeX is 1/72.27 inch, but 1 point in, e.g., Microsoft Word would be 1/72 inch.

BTW: There are classes like `memoir` or the KOMA-Script classes, e.g., `scrartcl`, that provides user interfaces to change the font sizes of headings. For example with KOMA-Script you could use:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper,sfdefaults=false]{scrartcl}% Option sfdefaults needs at least KOMA-Script 3.39
\usepackage{lmodern} % use free scalable fonts

\setkomafont{section}{\fontsize{16}{20}\selectfont}

\title{test}
\author{R P}
\date{April 2023}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

\end{document}
```